# Different Item Active for Bootstrap Carousel on each page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I am using wordpress with bootstrap from twitter. I want to use different item active for each page for the carousel.

For example: when the page is_page('Kontakt') the item active in the carousel shouldn't be the first picture, but the second.

Code:

```
 <div class="item active">
  <img src="http://testserver.webdesign-solution.net/sonnenhof-hotel/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/header-bild.png" alt="Chania">
</div>

<div class="item">
  <img src="http://testserver.webdesign-solution.net/sonnenhof-hotel/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/header-bild2.png" alt="Flower">
</div>
```

How can I solve that?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use is_page() wordpress function?

```
<div class="item <?php if ( is_page('Kontakt') ) { echo "active"; } ?>">
  <img src="http://testserver.webdesign-solution.net/sonnenhof-hotel/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/header-bild.png" alt="Chania">
</div>

<div class="item <?php if ( is_page('xxxxxxx') ) { echo "active"; } ?>">
  <img src="http://testserver.webdesign-solution.net/sonnenhof-hotel/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/header-bild2.png" alt="Flower">
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, this helps a lot but it doesn't work right. I need custom headers just for 4 sites. The others should have the standard item active.